# Toric edge ring in Macaulay2

Tags: graph-theory, macaulay2

Consider the following bipartite graph $G$, given by $V(G)= \{ s_1,s_2,s_3 \} \cup \{t_1,t_2\}$ and $E(G)=\{ \{ s_1,t_1\},\{s_1,t_2\},\{s_2,t_1\},\{s_2,t_2\},\{s_3,t_2\} \}.$

I want to define the toric edge ring of $G$, that is $K[s_1t_1,s_1t_2,s_2t_1,s_2t_2,s_3t_2],$ in `Macaulay2` ($K$ is a field). Do you know a way?

The following doesn't work:

`R=QQ[s_1..s_3,t_1,t_2];`

`S=K[s_1*t_1,s_1*t_2,s_2*t_1,s_2*t_2,s_3*t_2];`

Comment: Consider also asking on the Macaulay2 Google group: https://groups.google.com/g/macaulay2

Comment: Also, it may be easier to define your ring as a quotient of a polynomial ring and then see: https://macaulay2.com/doc/Macaulay2/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/_quotient_springs.html

Comment: For the ring that I need to study is better the toric rapresentation as edge ring unfortunately... So I should work on Macaulay2 using that in order to make easier the computations